# Network connection drops down after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: upgrade, network-manager, internet, resolv.conf, 19.04

I can make it connect temporarily by restarting resolv.conf and network-manager services. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Here's the additional info while it was working
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kdpB6R42Bb/

Answer (score 0):

What is the space in `name server`? Can you delete the space and try again? And if it does not help you, please try to turn off IPv6 as the following.

Please add

`net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1`

`net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1`

`net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1`

to

`/etc/sysctl.conf`

and then type the following command and press Enter on a command line

`sudo sysctl -p`

Next, please create a new file `/etc/rc.local` and add these contents

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/rc.local

# Load kernel variables from /etc/sysctl.d
/etc/init.d/procps restart

exit 0
```

and give the permission to execute to the file

```
chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
```